# Modifying to a style to include all websites except google docs (Stylish)

Tags: css, regex, google-docs, stylish

I'm modifying a  style called [Midnight Surfing - Global Dark Style](https://userstyles.org/styles/23516/midnight-surfing-global-dark-style%22Midnight%20Surfing%20-%20Global%20Dark%20Style%22)  with the Firefox plugin Stylish. I'm trying to use it's existing rule types but exclude google docs because it makes it unreadable. I like how they have it setup to not modify the toolbar or the option pages using this

`@-moz-document url-prefix(http://), url-prefix(https://), url-prefix(ftp://), url-prefix(file://)`

So I thought maybe I could do this same effect with regex but with the one exception that it doesn't apply the style to google docs. I tested the regex on http://www.rubular.com/r/nq1YVyIqZl and it appears to work however the regex I use below for the Stylish style doesn't seem to work. Any help is appreciated. I am not that experienced with regex or Stylish. This is pretty much my first attempt modifying a Stylish style

`@-moz-document regexp("^(?=.*(?:https:\/\/|http:\/\/|ftp:\/\/|file:\/\/))(?!.*(?:docs.google)).*$")`